# Iterate trough df and apply function if condition is met

Tags: python, pandas

Considering the bellow df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = [(3,5,7), (2,4,6),(5,8,9)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A','B','C'])
```

I want to iterate trough each row and check if value from C is grater than 8 in this way:

- If value of column C it's less than 8, append that row to another df called df2
- if value from column C is grater then 8, I apply a function that takes the max value of column C, and adds it to my current value

This function looks like this:

```
def increase_value(max_value):
     max_value= max(df['B'])
     df['C'] = df['C'] + max_value
     return df
```

I tried to create function that does all the above and then call it

I tried to make a function that iterate the df, takes each row and apply the 2 conditions

```
def check_value(df):
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['C'] < 8:
            df2 = df2.append(row)
        else:
            max_b_value = max(df['B'])
            row = increase_value(max_b_value)
            df2 = df2.append(row)
    return df2
df2 = check_value(df)
```

This is not what i want because it's duplicating rows, instead of just applying the `increase_value` function

I know there are other ways of doing this, but I need to use those 2 functions. Can someone please, tell me what I am doing wrong ? Also is this the best way to extract each row from the df?

Expected output:
for the last row 9 is grater than 8 and should apply the increase_value function. so for last row the value of column C will be 9 + 8 = 17

```
----------------
| A |  B | C   |
| 3 |  5 | 7   |  
| 2 |  4 | 6   |
| 5 |  8 | 17  |
----------------
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: There seems to be something wrong: `C` is never used in your `increase` function. I also yet don't understand what you are trying to to with `max_b_value`

Comment: IIUC, you only need do `row['C'] = row['C'] + max_b_value` in `increase_value` function.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. Please, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi, I added a reproductible example

Comment: Your `increase_value()` should take `df` as argument, not `max_value`

Comment: this gives another error TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: What! 9 + 8 = 16 ???

Comment: 9 is the initial value of C and 8 is the max value of column B

Comment: 9 + 8 = 17, no?

Comment: yes, sorry, to less sleep

Comment: Why you need this 2 function and loop? It's suboptimized?

Comment: That's just an example. I have larger dfs. My goal is to extract each row from the df, if that row meets a condition, apply a function and append it. If it does not meet the condition, append it as it is

Comment: @user3619789 if the row with `df['B'].max()` gets removed from `df` in one iteration, do you want to continue comparing values of `B` against it, or use the new `max` in the following iterations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

took the liberty to refactor and annotate [sharmu1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339310/sharmu1)'s more concise and performant answer to somewhat similar function input/output:

```py
def check_value_new(df):
    temp_df = df.loc[df['C'] < 8] # temp_df that only has rows that meet this condition
    df2 = temp_df.copy() # create a copy to set as df2, don't need to use concat
    return df2

def add_max(df):
    max_b_val = df['B'].max()
    
    df['C'] = np.where(
        df['C'] >= 8, # 'if' column "C" >= 8
        df['C'] + max_b_val, # add max value of b columns
        df['C'] # else: stay the same
    )
    return df

data = [(3,5,7), (2,4,6),(5,8,9)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A','B','C']) 

# get df2
df2 = check_value_new(df)

# process df
df = add_max(df)
```

output (printed):

```
df:
   A  B   C
0  3  5   7
1  2  4   6
2  5  8  17

df2:
   A  B  C
0  3  5  7
1  2  4  6
```

solution for original functions:

```py
import pandas as pd

def check_value(df):
    df2_list = [] # to be converted into dataframe
    max_b_value = df['B'].max()
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['C'] < 8:
            df2_list.append(row)
            # only append if you want to add to df2
        else:
            # increase value by adding it to the row in-place
            row['C'] += max_b_value 
            # dont need to apend because not adding to df2
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2_list)
    return df2

data = [(3,5,7), (2,4,6),(5,8,9)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A','B','C'])

df2 = check_value(df)
```

output (printed):

```
df:
   A  B   C
0  3  5   7
1  2  4   6
2  5  8  17

df2:
   A  B  C
0  3  5  7
1  2  4  6
```

Answer (score 2):

"Also is this the best way to extract each row from the df?"

You should make use of *vectorisation* rather than iteration. Try the following instead:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [0],
    'B': [0],
    'C': [0],
})

df2 = pd.concat([
    df2,
    df.loc[df['C'] < 8],
])
```

And for the other task:

```
df['C'] = np.where(
    df['C'] > 8,
    df['C'] + max(df['B']),
    df['C']
)
```

Output:

```
print(df)

   A  B   C
0  3  5   7
1  2  4   6
2  5  8  17

print(df2)

   A  B  C
0  0  0  0
0  3  5  7
1  2  4  6
```

Comment: What OP said was "if value from column C is grater then 8..." so I used > (granted the code below then contradicts this)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your functions, use:

```
def increase_value(row, max_value):
     row['C'] = row['C'] + max_value
     return row

def check_value(df):
    max_b_value = df['B'].max()
    data = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['C'] < 8:
            data.append(row)
        else:
            row = increase_value(row, max_b_value)
            data.append(row.copy())
    return pd.concat(data, axis=1).T

df2 = check_value(df)
```

Output:

```
>>> df2
   A  B   C
0  3  5   7
1  2  4   6
2  5  8  33
```